# Elasticsearch insensitive search by term

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got next query for search

```
    {  
       "query":{  
          "bool":{  
             "must":[  
                {  
                   "term":{  
                      "cardrecord.fields.name.raw":"HERE_IS_SOME_NAME"
                   }
                }
             ],
             "must_not":[  

             ],
             "should":[  

             ]
          }
       },
       "from":0,
       "size":50,
       "sort":[  

       ],
       "facets":{  

       }
    }
```

How can I modify the query for case insensetive search by term? I can add some more description if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the fields are analyzed using `Standard Analyzer` by default. If `"index":"not_analyzed"` is specified in `mapping` then the field will not be analyzed

`Standard Analyzer` converts the input string to lowercase and splits with whitespace and special characters. so in your case, `HERE_IS_SOME_NAME` will be split into tokens `some`, `name`. But the tokens`here` and `is` will not be created as they are english adverbs.

Same thing happens when you search for `"cardrecord.fields.name.raw"` field. It splits into tokens and searches for all documents with that tokens in specific field (using `Standard Analyzer`). P.S: Separate or different `analyzer` can be configured for searching also.

so match query searches for all documents with `some` and `name` tokens. Hence you would have got additional documents.

`term query` specifically looks for exact case and full word match. But it will not match any document since tokens are already `split` and `lowercase`

Follow these steps for your requirement:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "cardrecord.fields.name.raw": {
          "type":  "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update this `mapping` for your `index` named `my_type` as per code given above. You need to create new index with new mapping though. Since update might not reflect.
Then try running your search query in your question.

Adding detailed sequence of query:

mapping:

```
  {
      "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
          "properties": {
            "cardrecord.fields.name.raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "store": "true"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Indexing document:

```
{
  "cardrecord.fields.name.raw": "HERE_IS_SOME_NAME"
}
```

search query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "cardrecord.fields.name.raw": "HERE_IS_SOME_NAME"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! My solution was to create a custom analyzer (Tokenizer = "keyword" and Filter = ["lowercase"]), add its to field and set field index analyzed while mapping is executing.

Answer (score 1):

use filter instead of query, this will reduce amount of processing a lot:

```
{  
   "filter":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "cardrecord.fields.name.raw":"HERE_IS_SOME_NAME"
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":[  

         ],
         "should":[  

         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":50,
   "sort":[  

   ],
   "facets":{  

   }
}
```

Comment: what version of ES do you use?

Comment: It seems you need use custom analyser

Answer (score 1):

Try using a match query

```
{  
       "query":{  
          "bool":{  
             "must":[  
                {  
                   "match":{  
                      "cardrecord.fields.name.raw":"HERE_IS_SOME_NAME"
                   }
                }
             ],
             "must_not":[  

             ],
             "should":[  

             ]
          }
       },
       "from":0,
       "size":50,
       "sort":[  

       ],
       "facets":{  

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `match` query, but you need to match the `cardrecord.fields.name` field, because the `raw` subfield is probably `not_analyzed` and thus won't work for case-insensitive matching.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "cardrecord.fields.name": "HERE_IS_SOME_NAME"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}
```

Comment: it works but in search result i see additional items. for example, i see four documents insted of one.

Comment: Yes, either because you're searching for several terms, or the field contains several terms that have been analyzed into distinct tokens.

Comment: It depends on what you need to achieve. You'll have to share a bit more of your case (sample document, mapping, etc) if you need deeper helper. Feel free to update your question with whatever could be useful.